# How to create a condition in protractor for when an element exists or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using Protractor JS. And the site is written in Angular JS.

So I have a toggle switch. And I noticed the value in the toggle switch goes from true to false and 
false to true when you switch it off or on.

I am trying create a condition when Protractor visits my page when it sees the toggle switch 'off' it will turn it 'on'. If the toggle switch is already 'on', it will first turn it 'off' then turn it 'on' again.

I came up with this code, but for some reason it is not working:

```
 if( expect(element(By.id('toggle-switch')).element(By.css('[value="false"]')).isDisplayed()) ) {
            element(By.id('toggle-switch')).click();
            console.log('in the if')
       }

       else{
           element(By.id('toggle-switch')).click();
           browser.sleep(3000);
           element(By.id('toggle-switch')).click();
           console.log('in the else')
       }
```

This code appears to work only for the if statement. For some reason it will never go to the else. Here is the error I'm receiving:

*NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[value=\"false\"]")*

**So then I tried**

`.isPresent()` instead of `.isDisplayed()`
I don't receive the above error anymore, but for some reason when using .isPresent() it always goes to the if statement and only runs that, and never the else statement. No errors displayed.

If there is a better way please let me know. This seems very limiting to not be able to create proper conditions in this framework.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Remember that `isDisplayed()` returns a promise, you can try with:

```
element(anyFinder).isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
    if ( result ) {
        //Whatever if it is true (displayed)
    } else {
        //Whatever if it is false (not displayed)
    }
});
```

Comment: You probably don't need `expect()` here.

Comment: I like your answer, thanks. But, wouldn't I end in an expectation error that would fail the test before getting to the "if" statement?
cause I need it to keep going, even if it returns false

Comment: ah I didn't see your last comment earlier, didn't refresh my screen. I will take out the expect().

Comment: yeah it worked thanks for your help. i just tried it. removed the unnecessary expect() I had.

Comment: Hi, when isDisplayed is false in the case when we have a non visible element in the site we are testing, can we change it to visible?

Comment: It's important to include a second (error) function in the arguments to `then` because if the element doesn't exist at all, this will result in an error that causes the spec to fail.

Answer (score 24):

`isDisplayed()` did not work for me. The API may have been changed. `isPresent()` is my solution:

```
    var logoutButton =  element(by.css('[ng-click="log_out()"]'));
    logoutButton.isPresent().then(function(result) {
    if ( result ) {
        logoutButton.click();
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that **[`isDisplayed()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed), as a lot of methods in WebDriverJS/Protractor, returns a [promise](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow#promises-and-the-control-flow)** which by definition is "truthy" which makes it difficult to debug problems like this.

Let's work through an example to get a better understanding.

Imagine, you have the following code, which may look okay at the first glance:

```
var elm = $("#myid");
if (elm.isDisplayed()) {
    // do smth
} else {
    // do smth else
}
```

Now, it has a serious problem. *`do smth else` part will never be reached*, since `elm.isDisplayed()` is not a boolean value - it is a promise. Even if the element is not displayed, you would still have `// do smth` part executed.

Instead, if you need to check the value of `isDisplayed()` to use inside a conditional expression, you have to *resolve the promise with `then()` explicitly*:

```
var elm = $("#myid");
elm.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
  if (isDisplayed) {
      // do smth
  } else {
      // do smth else
  }
});
```

---

There is also a way to catch these kind of errors without even running the code - statically with [`ESLint`](http://eslint.org/) and [`eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor). There is a [relevant rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-promise-in-if.md) that watches if certain Protractor methods are used inside `if` conditions directly.

Here is what it would output for the code above:

```
$ eslint test.js
test.js
  2:1  warning  Unexpected "isDisplayed()" inside if condition  protractor/no-promise-in-if
```

Answer (score 1):

Or try this solution implemented from the top of my head, Schedules a command to test if an element is present on the page. If any errors occur while evaluating the wait, they will be allowed to propagate.

```
function alwaysSwitchOn(element) {
   browser.driver.isElementPresent(element).then(function(isPresent) {
      if (isPresent) {
        isPresent = true;
      } 
      else {
        browser.driver.wait(function () {
          return browser.driver.isElementPresent(element);
        }, 5000);
      }
      // to fail the test, then uncomment this line
      //expect(isPresent).toBeTruthy();
   }).then(function () {
      if (element.getAttribute('value') === 'OFF') {
         element.click();
      }
      else {
         // turn it OFF
         element.click();
         // turn it back ON
         element.click();
      }
   });
}
```

fn usage is to keep trying again and again for 5 seconds till it's `true`. if the element cannot be found within `5 sec` then it'll result in an error code; No such an element is found.Note, If the condition is fulfilled before wait (`5s`) it'll quickly move to `then(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

### If you're in 2021 or the following years

Forget about `.then()`. Do this instead:

```
it('test case', async () => {
  if (await element(anyFinder).isDisplayed()) {
    // Whatever if it is true (displayed)
  } else {
    // Whatever if it is false (not displayed)
  }
});
```