# Protractor - How to validate that an element is not visible

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

This question is closely related to the solutions given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947094/how-to-create-a-condition-in-protractor-for-when-an-element-exists-or-not)

In my test script, I need to go to login script and need to logout in case the browser logs in automatically in the app. So following the solutions provided in the question [How to create a condition in protractor for when an element exists or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947094/how-to-create-a-condition-in-protractor-for-when-an-element-exists-or-not), I have created this script:

```
 beforeEach(function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.get(globalVariables.loginMain);
    globalVariables.User_Menu_Dropdown.isDisplayed().then(function(Login_Menu) {

        if (Login_Menu) {

            globalVariables.User_Menu_Dropdown.click();
            browser.wait(globalVariables.until.presenceOf(globalVariables.logOut_Button), 3000, 'The Logout menu too long to appear in the DOM');
            globalVariables.logOut_Button.click();
            browser.wait(globalVariables.until.presenceOf(globalVariables.Email_Input_box), 3000, 'The User Input box too long to appear in the DOM');
        } else {

            console.log("the app is on the login page")//do nothing

        }

    });
```

But when I run the script, I still get the following error 
`"Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, img[class="img-thumb-xs mr-1 align-middle"])".` What am I doing wrong here? What is the best approach to achieve it?

Comment: If I am not wrong.. in order to use isDisplayed you need to be sure that the element exists otherwise you will have this error, so first validate if 'isPresent' is true and then if it is, you check if it is displayed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the **ExpectedConditions** in your case.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be no longer visible on the dom.
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf($('#abc')), 5000);
```

or you can use the **not** condition which will lead to the same result

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be no longer visible on the dom.
browser.wait(EC.not(EC.visibilityOf($('#abc'))), 5000);
```