# Test stops with conditional action on element.isDisplayed and element is not displayed

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

In my test I have a condition to check if a popup is displayed. If so, the cancel button is clicked. But if the popup is not shown the test stops with the error: 
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator (*locator of popup*)

I found an old post with the same problem:
[How to create a condition in protractor for when an element exists or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947094/how-to-create-a-condition-in-protractor-for-when-an-element-exists-or-not)

but the solutions mentioned did not work for me.

isDisplayed() gives: NoSuchElementError

elementPresent() gives: timeout

my code:

```
el.isDisplayed().then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    // click cancel
                }
            });
```

I expect the test to continue when the popup is not displayed.
But, if the popup is not displayed then I get an error or timeout.

Comment: share the html of `el` and your implementation

Comment: I'm happy to share html, but you can use any html to replicate this issue

Comment: Is the popup one of the default browser alert windows or some customer popup you have created?

Comment: custom popup which can be found with the selector:
    `md-dialog[name='customActionDialog']`

Comment: I highly recommend to start using `async/await` keywords to make your code more readable and syntax would be much easier to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If the element is not present, you cannot check its visibility.
You could try:

```
     el.isPresent().then(isPresent => {
        if (isPresent) {
            el.isDisplayed().then(isDisplayed => {
                if (isDisplayed) {
                    cancel.click();
                } else { // so you'll know that it had failed:
                    expect(isDisplayed).toBeTruthy();
                }
                // the rest of the code
            });
        }
        expect(isPresent).toBeTruthy(); // again, so you'll know that it had failed:
        // the rest of the code
    });
```

Now, I know this is not the most elegant of solutions, but it should work. Also, if there are more steps to be done after cancel that do not depend on it and you want the test to continue regardless of the popup's visibility, you could remove `expect`s, but that would mean test would pass even when popup does not appear and you'd have no way of knowing.

Comment: same happens with this code at line 1 >> isPresent() stops the test because of a timeout.

Comment: @Crama what kind of timeout

Comment: the above code should work. If it doesn't the problem is not in condition or likely in your framework set up or somewhere else in the spec

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
if(await el.isPresent() === true) {
        // click cancel
    }
```

Comment: error: 
Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'Promise<boolean>' and 'boolean'.

Comment: @Crama Do mark the answer correct if it really helped you. Thanks